# Loop over AngularFirestoreCollection Observable in Angular method

Tags: angular, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Angularfire2 with the new Firestore database. In my method I'm doing a query like this:

```
const questionsRef = this.afs.collection('questions', ref => ref.where('category', '==', category).limit(10));
```

Now I need to get the results in a loop so I can manipulate the data and create a new document in a different collection with the values from that result.

This is how one of the documents returned from the collection is structured:

```
{
  "description": "Test question",
  "category": "dOULqW4jMkC4E4iopOyk",
  "answers": [
    {
      "description": "test answer",
      "correct": true
    },
    {
      "description": "test answer 2",
      "correct": false
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to make a copy of the results returned from `questionsRef` but add a new field to every answer called `"selected": false`.

I realise I also need to somehow wait until all the data is loaded, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going through the same thing on FB collections now. I think there's a mind-shift to approaching it but I'm still struggling with it. Here's a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47378910/firebase-firestore-collection-count-with-angularfire-2?rq=1) about it but I've just iterated through the collection like this:

```js
      var questionsRef = this.afs.collection('questions', ref => {
         return ref.where('category', '==', category).limit(10);
      });

      var questionsCol = questionsRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
         map(actions => actions.map(a => {
            return a.payload.doc.data(); // get id using a.payload.doc.id
         }))
      );

      questionsCol.forEach(doc => {
         // operate on the doc here...
      });
```

Hope that helps.