# Firebase firestore collection count with angularFire 2

Tags: firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get the total number of the documents that exist in firestore. 
I don't want to get the data only the total number of inside Products collection I have **200.000** items is that possible with Angular 4-5, not angular.js

Can someone expert tell me how I can achieve that ??

My code so far and is not work

```
  get_total_messages() {
    this.messages_collection = this.afs.collection<MessageEntity>('messages');
    return this.messages_collection.snapshotChanges();
  }
```

#### End this is how I try to get the data but is not what I want;

```
this.firebase_Service.get_total_messages().subscribe( data => {
   console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no API to get the count of the number of documents in a Firestore collection. This means that the only ways to get the count are:

1. Get all documents and count them client-side.
2. Store the count as a separate property and update that as you add/remove documents.

Both approaches are quite common in NoSQL databases, with the second of course being a lot more efficient as the number of documents grows.

Firebase provides a [sample of using Cloud Functions to keep a counter](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/child-count). While this sample is written for the Firebase Realtime Database, it can easily be modified to work on Cloud Firestore too.

Firestore also provides documentation on [running aggregation queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation) and [running distributed counters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters). Both seem slightly more involved than the first sample I linked though.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.firebase_Service.get_total_messages().subscribe(data => this.totalnumber = data.length);
```

Now you can get total number of messages

Comment: Ganza the @Frank above says there is no way to count the collection docks If I use your way I need to download 200.000 docks that 200Mb of data you need 3 weeks to download all that and if you want to count all that the RAm is gonna explode. Thank you but this is not what I want. Welcome to stackoverflow . Ganza

Answer (score 0):

luckily , i've solved somehow using the code,
try this, and it works well .

```
this.db.collection('User').valueChanges()
.subscribe( result => {
console.log(result.length);
})
```

Comment: This is not the best approach as if we have 1000 documents and we need just count, Here firebase pricing calculates as 1000 documents.